# HSQLDB Restore With a Button

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, database-backups, database-restore

I give a user a tab to press and backup his data in a specified location in the file system of the HSQLDB using this SQL statement 
[backup database to directory_name blocking] with a preparedStatement, which runs fine.

I want give the user a tab to restore his data from that location...but no SQL made for this task except this command line , while DB is shutdown :

java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackupMain --extract tardir/backup.tar dbdir.

Is there a way to invoke this command line in programmatic way by pressing a tab (also after DB shutdown)?

P.S: telling a user to use a command line, going to be awkward ,or worse not possible to do.

Comment: what You understand under word "tab" ? Usually is easy to duplicate main class functionality from java open source projects, calling it in single JVM ("programatic way")

Comment: @jacek Cz... Sorry I meant a button. How to get such functionality?

Comment: Open source code of DbBackupMain  and look, specially main() method, do your own in similar way. Maybe exist some other way, i dont use hsql internals

Comment: @Jacek Cz... Thanks :)

Comment: usually we dont add database jars at compile path and import (use abstractions, mainly JDBC driver) - in this (hypothetical) case, import classes etc ...  http://book2s.com/java/src/package/org/hsqldb/lib/tar/dbbackupmain.html